# How to set up a lighttpd modular config for several vhosts

Tags: lighttpd, virtualhost, server-settings

I have a question regarding `lighttpd` best practices for vhosts setups. I wanted to set up a modular config for several vhosts with splitted config files to be able to enable/disable specific vhosts easily. Platform is Debian 8.2 running lighttpd 1.4.35. Requirements are as follows:

- the server should bind to a public NIC and listen on port 80 for the public vhosts
- it also should listen on port 81 for machine2machine communication only
- additionally it should bind to a NIC on an internal network (both ports 80/81)
- vhosts should be defined in separate files under `conf-enabled/vhostN.conf`

So I did set up as follows (1.2.3.4 be the IP of the public NIC, 10.0.0.1 the IP inside the private network). In the central `lighttpd.conf` I first define a default server binding to both IPs:

```
server.bind = "1.2.3.4"                 # public default server
server.port = 80
$SERVER["socket"] == "10.0.0.1:80" {}   # private default server
```

The vhosts are set up in separate files under `conf-enabled/`, say `vhost1.conf`, `vhost2.conf` etc. I tried to split the following directives across the config files:

```
## This is for machine2machine communication on port 81 over the Internet
$SERVER["socket"] == "1.2.3.4:81" {
...
}
## This is for machine2machine communication on port 81 inside the private net
else $SERVER["socket"] == "10.0.0.1:81" {
...
}
## This is vhost 1, accessible through Internet and private network
else $HTTP["host"] =~ "^vhost1.do.main$" {
...
}
## This is vhost 2
else $HTTP["host"] =~ "^vhost2.do.main$" {
...
}
```

and so on. Everything works so far if I put it all in one big config file. But when I split the config into separate files, it seems that the `else` gives syntax errors since it is not honored across the included cfg files.

While the `else` would be redundant between the vhosts sections triggered by the HTTP `Host` header, it is not so in relation to the `$SERVER["socket"]` section. If I would remove the `else`, it would be possible to access all vhosts through port 81, inheriting the setup for the m2m host in addition to the ones for named vhosts.

Furthermore, I could not figure out how to define the section for m2m comm in only one block with two `$SERVER["socket"]` directives for two IPs, so I had to duplicate the setup for the same vhost bound to port 81. If there is a way to combine two `$SERVER["socket"]` directives for a single section, I could use the default server for port 81 and surround the named vhosts with a `$SERVER["socket"]` directive binding to port 80.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a trick I didn't see in the docs to accomplish such a vhost setup with separate cfg files resulting in the same effect as using `else`?
2. Can two `$SERVER["socket"]` directives be combined to avoid having to duplicate the same vhost twice and to encapsulate a bunch of named vhosts, thus avoiding the need for the `else`? I tested with the `||` operator, but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Every file has to be syntactically correct. What you can always do is to concatenate a directory and files and use this one. After every change to one of the source files do `cat vhosts-conf/* > conf-enabled/vhosts.conf`. And you can also always imitate a logical or with `conf1 { include common.conf } cond2 { include common.conf }`.

Comment: Sebix, thank you for your answer. The suggestion with the `include`s is very helpful to merge the port 81 config blocks into a single block. Also concatenation of single configs is a good idea; I probably will integrate this in lighttpd's perl script parsing the config directory. Thanks again!